# Is there a way to transform this into code a stream?

Tags: java, java-stream

There can't be any side effects in functional programming (stream), but I'm having trouble with that. I want to create a new object from values that I pick up along the way. I already have the `Ship ship` object and the `Island buyIsland` object and the objective is to calculate all possibilities from the list of `List<String> cargoNames` and the list of `List<Island> sellIslands` so that I can get the `cargoSellPrice` to make the profit calculation for that particular possibility.

The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to have a way to get those values back once I map to create a new stream. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I need to have all 4 of those to create a new ProfitOption object:

`new ProfitOption(buyIsland, cargoName, sellIsland, ship, levelOfDetail)`

Obs: `levelOfDetail` is a default value

So, is there a way to convert the code below into a stream to make the code a bit more readable?

```
List<ProfitOption> profitOptions = new ArrayList<>();
Island buyIsland = islandCargoPriceDataTable.get(buyIslandName);
Collection<Island> islandList = islandCargoPriceDataTable.values();
Ship ship = shipPropertiesInfo.get(shipName);

Set<String> cargoList = buyIsland.getIslandCargoPrices().keySet();
for (String cargoName : cargoList) {
    int cargoBuyPrice = buyIsland.getIslandCargoPrices().get(cargoName).getPrice();
    for (Island sellIsland : islandList) {
        int cargoSellPrice = sellIsland.getIslandCargoPrices().get(cargoName).getPrice();
        if (cargoSellPrice > cargoBuyPrice) {
            profitOptions.add(new ProfitOption(
                    buyIsland, cargoName, sellIsland, ship, levelOfDetail));
        }
    }
}
```

The solution provided didn't really solve the problem, unfortunately. It seemed that it would work.

https://prnt.sc/T8tZ2sXAfrJc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: The key is going to be the `collect(toList())` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a stream over the `cargoList` and then generate a portion of `ProfitOption` objects by streaming over `sellIsland` and filtering cost-efficient prices.

Since every cargo in the `cargoList` can potentially produce multiple `ProfitOption` objects, in order to do transform a `Stream<String>` (where each element represents a cargo) into `Stream<ProfitOption>` you can use [`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) operation.

That's how it might look like:

```
Collection<Island> islandList = // initialing buyIsland 
Set<String> cargoList =         // initialing cargoList
Island buyIsland =              // initialing buyIsland
Ship ship =                     // initialing ship

List<ProfitOption> profitOptions = cargoList.stream()
    .flatMap(cargoName -> islandList.stream()
        .filter(sellIsland -> sellIsland.getIslandCargoPrices().get(cargoName).getPrice()
                            > buyIsland.getIslandCargoPrices().get(cargoName).getPrice())
        .map(sellIsland -> 
                new ProfitOption(buyIsland, cargoName, sellIsland, ship, levelOfDetail))
        )
    ).toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really understand why the flatMap with the stream inside instead of just using a normal map, but it works. I'll try to learn this, thanks.

Comment: it turns out that this option didn't really work... https://prnt.sc/T8tZ2sXAfrJc

Comment: @Reborn `map()` is meant for *one-to-one* transformations, `flatMap()` facilitates *one-to-many* transformations. And in this case you need *one-to-many*. `flatMap` expects a **stream** of new elements not a collection, that's how it was implemented, have a look at the documentation-link provided in the answer.

Comment: @Reborn Regarding your editing: posting images of the code doesn't improve the question, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question) . Post your **stream-based** code as a **text** and copy-past from the console the **compilation error** it produces (as a **text** as well).

Comment: @Reborn So, your question would be more readable if it would have the following structure: **first part** - brief introduction of the task containing your code based on `for`-loops and  explanation of what it does, **second part** - your attempt with streams and **exact text** of the compilation error (no images).